# Eventhough I have "self" inside of the class method, I am keep on receiving "train() takes 0 positional arguments but 3 were given"

Tags: python, neural-network

I've been searching the matter on stackoverflow and saw similar questions,
but none of them had the exact same matter as I have.

I'm trying to run a class method called train(), which has 3 parameters including "self"

But I am keep on having the error:

> train() takes 0 positional arguments but 3 were given

I was wondering what is the matter, and how I can solve it?

Below is the code I am trying to run:

```
>>> n = nn.neuralNetwork(3, 3, 3, 0.3)
>>> c = n.train([1.0, 0.5, -1.5], [5,5,5])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#35>", line 1, in <module>
    c = n.train([1.0, 0.5, -1.5], [5,5,5])
TypeError: train() takes 0 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

And below is how the class nn looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.special

#neural network class definition
class neuralNetwork:

    #initialize the neural network
    def __init__(self, inputnodes, hiddennodes, outputnodes, learningrate):
        #set number of nodes in each input, hidden, output layer
        self.inodes = inputnodes
        self.hnodes = hiddennodes
        self.onodes = outputnodes

        self.lr = learningrate

        self.wih = np.random.normal(0.0, pow(self.inodes, -0.5), (self.hnodes, self.inodes))
        self.who = np.random.normal(0.0, pow(self.hnodes, -0.5), (self.onodes, self.hnodes))

        # activation function is the sigmoid function
        self.activation_function = lambda x : scipy.special.expit(x)

        pass



    def train(self, inputs_list, targets_list):

        inputs = np.array(inputs_list, ndmin = 2).T
        targets = np.array(targets_list, ndmin = 2).T


        hidden_inputs = np.dot(self.wih, inputs)

        hidden_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs)


        final_inputs = np.dot(self.who, hidden_outputs)

        final_outputs = self.activation_function(final_inputs)


        output_errors = targets - final_outputs

        hidden_errors = np.dot(self.who.T, output_errors) 

        self.who += self.lr * numpy.dot((output_errors * final_outputs *
                                        (1.0-final_outputs)), np.transpose(hidden_outputs))

        self.wih += self.lr * numpy.dot((hidden_errors * hidden_outputs *
                                         (1.0-hidden_outputs)), np.transpose(inptus))
```

Comment: What does `n.train.__module__` contain?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking. Are you asking what the train() method is? That is on the posting. :)

Comment: You don't show the definition of `nn`. Are you sure that `nn` is ***that*** `neuralNetwork`? That you haven't loaded a different module for `neuralNetwork` that has a zero-argument `train()` method? @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams is asking you to confirm that the `__module__` field for `n`'s `train` method is the one you are expecting.

Comment: @JohnBurger Hi, thanks for your reply. I'm sorry that I missed to mention. nn is module's name where neuralNetwork class is defined. So I had "import nn" before I ran the code.

Comment: Are `target` and `targets` in the function definition supposed to be the same variable?

Comment: @DyZ oh yeah thank you. You are right. I fixed it. But the code still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can use ipython to run it:

```
In [2]: import nn

In [3]: n = nn.neuralNetwork(3, 3, 3, 0.3)

In [4]: c = n.train([1.0, 0.5, -1.5], [5,5,5])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-538d3963f639> in <module>()
----> 1 c = n.train([1.0, 0.5, -1.5], [5,5,5])

~/zhidao/nn.py in train(self, inputs_list, targets_list)
     40
     41
---> 42         output_errors = target - final_outputs
     43
     44         hidden_errors = np.dot(self.who.T, output_errors)

NameError: name 'target' is not defined

In [5]: n.train??  # type double `?` will show the source code of `def train`
```